# Training and Validation Accuracy does not change at all

Tags: python, graph, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I am trying to rebuild a model from a research paper. No errors happen, but the accuracy metric is not is not changing. I tried lots of different solutions, and most of them usually ends up in errors that I have to trace till I lost hope.

The data is graphs that are created using PyTorch Geometric. I made sure that the data is actually valid and there are no problems with them. Each graph is 18 nodes, with 18 features per node. The graphs are sparse, the number of edges differ from one graph to another. The edges of the graphs are weighted.

The full code along with data is available here on [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1TcEOx4Y0OJccilGvSa8UiGUvjVvp27jg?usp=sharing) for your convenience.

In case you prefer the code to be here.
The required model to build:
[image: Model Description]

```
class GCNModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GCNModel, self).__init__()
        # Block1

        self.conv1 = GCNConv(in_channels=18, out_channels=64)  # Graph Convolution
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.conv2 = GCNConv(in_channels=64, out_channels=32)  # Graph Convolution
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool = global_mean_pool

        # Block2
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32, 32)     # Fully Connected
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(0.3)  # Dropout layer with p=0.3
        self.relu3 = nn.ReLU()

        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(32, 16)     #  Fully Connected
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(0.3)  # Dropout layer with p=0.3
        self.relu4 = nn.ReLU()

        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(16, 1)       # Fully Connected

    def forward(self, data):
        x, edge_index, edge_attr, batch = data.x, data.edge_index, data.edge_attr, data.batch

        # Block1
        x = self.conv1(x, edge_index, edge_attr)  # Pass edge_attr to the convolution
        x = self.relu1(x)

        # ReLU Graph Convolution
        x = self.conv2(x, edge_index, edge_attr)  # Pass edge_attr to the convolution
        x = self.relu2(x)

        # Average pooling along the spatial dimension
        x = self.pool(x, batch)

        # Block2 Fully Connected
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.dropout1(x)  # Apply dropout
        x = self.relu3(x)

        # ReLU Fully Connected
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.dropout2(x)  # Apply dropout
        x = self.relu4(x)

        # ReLU Fully Connected
        x = self.fc3(x)

        return x
```

The training, validation and testing procedure:

```
# Instantiate GCNModel
model = GCNModel()

# Define optimizer and learning rate
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, weight_decay=0.0001)

# Define your loss function
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# Define the data loaders
train_loader = DataLoader(data_train, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(data_val, batch_size=64, shuffle=False)
test_loader = DataLoader(data_test, batch_size=64, shuffle=False)

# Training loop
def train(epoch):
    model.train()
    for data in train_loader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data)
        loss = criterion(output, data.y.view(-1, 1).float())
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

# Function to compute accuracy
def compute_accuracy(loader):
    model.eval()
    predictions = []
    labels = []
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data in loader:
            output = model(data)
            predictions.extend(torch.argmax(output, axis=1).cpu().numpy())  # Use argmax for predicted labels
            labels.extend(data.y.cpu().numpy())
    accuracy = accuracy_score(labels, predictions)
    return accuracy

# Training and validation
num_epochs = 50  # Train for 50 epochs
for epoch in range(1, num_epochs + 1):
    train(epoch)
    train_acc = compute_accuracy(train_loader)  # Compute accuracy on training data
    val_acc = compute_accuracy(val_loader)
    print(f"Epoch [{epoch}/{num_epochs}], Train Acc: {train_acc:.4f}, Val Acc: {val_acc:.4f}")

# Testing
test_acc = compute_accuracy(test_loader)
print(f"Testing Accuracy: {test_acc:.4f}")
```

Output:

```
Epoch [1/50], Train Acc: 0.4471, Val Acc: 0.4470
Epoch [2/50], Train Acc: 0.4471, Val Acc: 0.4470
.
.
.
Epoch [50/50], Train Acc: 0.4471, Val Acc: 0.4470
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been solved. It required editing the model and re-writing it from scratch. I used SkLearn to compute the accuracy too. The code is available in the provided Colab link above, as long as it is available online.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the last layer ends with a fully connected layer as per your code, you missed inputting the Softmax layer for prediction, hence the model is not really learning anything significant.
Modify the forward method of your code, add softmax in the last layer like this:

```
class GCNModel(nn.Module):
    # ... (other parts of the code)

    def forward(self, data):
        # ... (previous parts of the forward method)

        # ReLU Fully Connected
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.dropout2(x)
        x = self.relu4(x)

        # Softmax Fully Connected (for multiclass classification)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = torch.softmax(x)  # Apply softmax activation

        return x
```

---

Edit 2:
I also found some inconsistencies with the model you build, the proper model should be this below according the the model configuration you provided:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class GraphConvolutionLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features, out_features):
        super(GraphConvolutionLayer, self).__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(in_features, out_features)

    def forward(self, x, adjacency_matrix):
        batch_size, num_nodes, _ = x.size()

        x = self.linear(x)
        x = torch.bmm(adjacency_matrix, x)

        return x

class GCNNModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GCNNModel, self).__init__()
        self.layers = nn.ModuleList([
            GraphConvolutionLayer(in_features=18, out_features=64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            GraphConvolutionLayer(in_features=64, out_features=32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.AvgPool2d(1, 32)
        ])
        
        self.fc_layers = nn.ModuleList([
            nn.Linear(in_features=32, out_features=32),  # Fully connected layer
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(in_features=32, out_features=16),  # Fully connected layer
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(in_features=16, out_features=1),   # Fully connected layer
            nn.Softmax(dim=1)  # Softmax layer
        ])

    def forward(self, x, adjacency_matrix):
        for layer in self.layers:
            x = layer(x, adjacency_matrix)
        
        # Average pooling along the spatial dimension
        x = torch.mean(x, dim=1, keepdim=True)
        
        for layer in self.fc_layers:
            x = layer(x)
        
        return x

# Create the GCNN model with both blocks
model = GCNNModel()

print(model)
```

print output:

```
GCNNModel(
  (layers): ModuleList(
    (0): GraphConvolutionLayer(
      (linear): Linear(in_features=18, out_features=64, bias=True)
    )
    (1): ReLU()
    (2): GraphConvolutionLayer(
      (linear): Linear(in_features=64, out_features=32, bias=True)
    )
    (3): ReLU()
    (4): AvgPool2d(kernel_size=1, stride=32, padding=0)
  )
  (fc_layers): ModuleList(
    (0): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=32, bias=True)
    (1): ReLU()
    (2): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=16, bias=True)
    (3): ReLU()
    (4): Linear(in_features=16, out_features=1, bias=True)
    (5): Softmax(dim=1)
  )
)
```

see, now it matches with your model configuration:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this haven't solved the problem. Instead, I added  ` self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1) `  in the model and ` x = self.softmax(x)`  in the forward method. I also decided to print the loss every epoch, and it was -0.  I made a change in the line regarding the loss statement, it became ` loss = criterion(output.view(-1), data.y.float()) `. Now I have numbers that change with minimal effect. I pushed the learning rate to 0.01, but the same problem. In all these cases, the values for accuracy does not change

Comment: I think in this case the optimizer found a local minimum already, Most likely reason is the optimizer is not suited to your dataset, try other optimizers such as SGD, and RMSProp. Also, try other activation non-linear functions such as sigmoid, this might help in improving the accuracy

Comment: I tried `optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, weight_decay=0.0001, momentum=0.9)`, with sigmoid activation. Almost nothing. The loss and accuracy do not change. I changed the loss function to be `criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()` instead. I see some changes in the loss. but the changes are not much from 0.69 till 0.63 and heavily fluctuating. The values of the accuracy do not change regardless of anything. Is there something wrong with how the accuracy is calculated especially the `predictions` and `labels` parts?

Comment: EDIT: I noticed that the values of  `output = model(data)` are very very small. What could be the problem here? Also, I would like to know if it is possible to have a long at the model implemented and the required model in the image above (Table 1)? Are there any mistakes in the implementation? Thank you

Comment: hey, I found some inconsistencies with the model you wrote, the layers don't match according to your paper. I will edit and my answer and provide you the codes there, It might be the reason why your model performance is bad

Comment: Thank you!! You can use the provided Colab link for the notebook if you are interested to check the edits in realtime.

Comment: Let me know if the corrected architecture I provided helped

Comment: Thank you. I am working on fixing the errors, as the way the inputs are provided to the layers is not compatible with the graphs. For example, we don't have an adjacency_matrix to provide, instead we have edge indices and edge attributes